# Why does it take two instructions to set a memory address?

Tags: assembly, mips

Why does MIPS take 2 instructions to set a memory address into register?

Isn't simply `la $4 (example), vals` enough?

Comment: Because MIPS instructions are 32-bit wide and thus cannot encode a 32-bit operand (like an address).

Comment: Thanks! `vals: .word 4, 5, 8, 0
.text
.globl main
main:
la $4, vals # Load $4 with 'vals‘ address.`

Am I saving the vals into the address $4, but it is taking only 1 instruction. Am I wrong?

Comment: [`la` is a pseudo-instruction, the assembler will emit a `lui` and a `ori` instruction](https://github.com/MIPT-ILab/mipt-mips/wiki/MIPS-pseudo-instructions).